# Set an Ember.js controller variable to an Ember Data object, not a promise

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, promise

I have a route that initially has no suggestion. Based on an action, I would like to grab a suggestions array with Ember Data, get the first suggestion and assign it to the controller. Here's what I've got:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('suggestion', null);
  },
  actions: {
    getSuggestion: function() {
      suggestion = this.store.find('suggestion').then(function(s) {
          return s.get('firstObject');
      });
      this.controller.set('suggestion', suggestion);
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is that the `suggestion` variable, after performing the `getSuggestion` action, it still a promise. How can I only set the controller variable after the promise is resolved? Or how can I let it resolve afterwards and have the variable updated with the actual object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the 'suggestion' inside 'then' block

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('suggestion', null);
  },
  actions: {
    getSuggestion: function() {
      controller = this.controller;
      this.store.find('suggestion').then(function(s) {
          suggestion =  s.get('firstObject');
          controller.set('suggestion', suggestion);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You are right! Thanks for pointing me. Accepted this answer because it was the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Set the property on resolution of the promise:

```
actions: {
    getSuggestion: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.store.find('suggestion').then(function(s) {
            self.controller.set('suggestion', s.get('firstObject'));
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change controller variable between controllers,

If you want to change controller variable of "home" controller then you need to include Home controller into your controller.

Example:-

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  needs: ['home'],
  changeVariable: function(){
    if(..){
      this.set('controllers.home.isMyHomePage', false);
    }else{
      this.set('controllers.home.isMyHomePage', true);
    }    
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this with RSVP?

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('suggestion', null);
  },
  actions: {
    getSuggestion: function() {
      var suggestions = this.store.find('suggestion');

      Ember.RSVP.all(suggestions).then(function(s) {
        this.controller.set('suggestion', s.get('firstObject'));
      }.bind(this));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `this` inside Ember.RSVP.all(suggestions).then(...) will have a different context.

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't double check what I wrote. Just for my personal interest: would that work?